# relationship between uniform Hypergraph maximum matching minimum vertex cover minimum clique partition

Tags: graph-theory

A k-$\bf{uniform}$ hypergraph $H = (V,E)$ consists of a set $V = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n\}$ of vertices and a set $E = \{e_1, e_2, \cdots , e_m\}$ of edges, each being a size $k$ subset of $V$. (Note: no multiple edges are allowed.)

A subset $M \subseteq E(H)$ is a *matching* if every pair of edges from $M$ has an empty intersection.

The *dual* $H^*$ of $H$ is a hypergraph whose vertices and edges are interchanged, so that the vertices are given by $\{e_1, e_2, \cdots , e_m\}$ and whose edges are given by $X = \{X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n\}$ where $X_j = \{e_j | v_j \in e_i \}$.

$\textbf{My question}$:

is it true that

size of maximum matching of $H$ $\leq$ size of maximum matching of $H^*$ $\leq$ size of minimum vertex cover of $H$,

and where does minimum clique partition of $H^*$ stand in this inequality??

Please correct me if I am wrong and give me some hint or what book chapter you think I should dig into. Thanks!